# How to switch Stripe test mode to live with same products

Tags: stripe-payments

I have an online Laravel app that takes subscriptions, and have been working on this for years with Stripe integration in test mode. Now that I'm ready to go live, I can't find clear indication as to how to flip the "live" switch. I know that I select live mode and use different keys, but it looks like the products I setup and tested on in test mode do not roll over, or don't exist in Live mode.

Do I have to set up a new set of products to match those in test mode, and how do I prevent this breaking if I get some small detail of the product in live mode wrong? It seems as thought there would be some sort of transition tool to allow the products that have been tested for an extensive period in test mode to simply persist into a live mode without having to do a start-over?

What am I missing....?

Comment: contact stripe developers on Discord channel

Comment: @OldProgrammer apologies for the noob question, but I can't find the Stripe dev group on Discord, and Discord wants me to respond to an invitation. Do you happen to know where I can sign up for this group?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a few products, you can [copy](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/manage-prices) your test mode pricing models to live mode via the Dashboard by clicking the `Copy to live mode` button on the product details page. However, this is a Dashboard only functionality and you’d need to re-create/ mirror your prices in live mode by creating these Products/ Prices via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/create) by using your live mode API [key](https://stripe.com/docs/keys).